# Is this proof of 7 > 6 correct?

Tags: solution-verification

High-schooler here. I tried to prove that 7 > 6 because it's fun:

### Try

#### Definitions

1D — $[a ≥ b] ↔ [a-(z) = b, z \in \mathbb{N}]$

2D — $[a ≥ b] ↔ [(a=b) \lor (a>b)]$

3D — $[a \neq b] ↔ ¬[a=b]$

#### Proof

Using the identity axiom ($a + 0 = a$), we know that:

1: $7 + 0 = 7$

2: $7 = 7$  Simplifying line 1 using itself ($7 + 0 = 7$)

3: $7 - (1) = 7 - (1)$  Subtracting both sides by $(1)$ (identity axiom)

4: $7 - (1) = 6$ Simplifying $7-(1)$ on the equation's right side

If we define the natural numbers using the Peano's Axioms, we can extract that $1 \in \mathbb{N}$ (means: *1 is a natural number*):

5: $7 - (1) = 6, 1 \in \mathbb{N}$

Now we can use 1D on line 5:

6: $7 ≥ 6$

Using 2D on line 6:

7: $(7=6) \lor (7>6)$

In order to don't prove too many things, we'll assume that $7 \neq 6$, even if we know it's true:

8: $7 \neq 6$

Using 3D on line 8:

9: $¬[7 = 6]$

Using logic (if A or B is/are true, and we know that A is false, then B is true) on lines 7 and 9:

10: $7>6$

*Quod erat demonstratum*: $7>6$

---

The definition 1D was adapted from the second paragraph of the answer of the question “what is the proof for 0 being less than 1?” in https://www.quora.com/What-is-proof-for-0-being-less-than-1. I didn't understand the answer, but I used his/her definition for it.

The definition 2D I took from the own name and idea of $≥$: “**lesser or greater** than”.

The definition 3D is the same thing as 2D. If $a+b$ is “a is **equal to** c", and $a \neq b$ is "a is ***not* equal to** b", it looked like a good definition: $[a \neq b] ↔ ¬[a=b]$

### Questions

For whom is going to answer, please:

Is the proof correct? If so, is there a way it could be better? If it's wrong, what is wrong?

By the way, did I use Q.E.D. (*Quod erat demonstratum*) correctly?

Thank you very much for reading this.

P.S.: I didn't say “high-schooler here” in the start to increase what I did. I did it to assure that people would understand that my maths background is high school, so they wouldn't use too complex explanations.

Comment: Seems okay. I personally prefer $\iff$ to ↔ and usually one would put QED at the very end of the proof

Comment: @user619755, me too. But I didn't remember how to write it and what I used seemed good enough. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: It’s great that you want to learn more math as a high school student. As a side piece of advice, I’d highly recommend using sources other than Quora (which is not always very reliable). For example there are lots of math lectures from good universities on YouTube.

Comment: @Funktorality. I hate Quora. Thank for the comment. I forgot to say it. Sorry.

Comment: @Schilive I think you can start with 2 rather than deducing it from 1.

Comment: @Schilive no reason to hate Quora just because it's not reliable as a math source, it's great for other things. In fact, I think it's pretty much the best social media platform

Comment: @l1lmbo, at least about linguistics, the amount of people that don't know what they're talking about and of incorrect is colossal.

Comment: One small comment: In 1D you should include a quantifier on the new variable $z$. Someone reading 1D right now might not know whether it is meant: "$a-z=b$ for some $z\in\mathbb{N}$" or "$a-z=b$ for all $z\in\mathbb{N}$". (You also don't really need parentheses around $z$, but that's not a big deal.) More generally, when defining a property $P$ of some objects $a_1,\ldots,a_n$, any new objects other than $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ introduced in the definition of $P$ should be given explicit and clear quantifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very happy to see people are still looking into the foundation of mathematics, the axioms this beautiful science started with. To answer your question:

$1$. I am quite positive your proof is correct and very rigorous. (I will ask a specialist and come with a confirmation)

$2$. Your $1D$ is equivalent to:

> $\forall x,y (x<y\Rightarrow\exists z(x+z=y))$ (Everything that happens here, happens over $\mathbb{N}$)

$2'$. Regarding the quora post, that guy used the following interpretation:

> The Peano axioms can be derived from set theoretic constructions of the natural numbers and axioms of set theory such as the [Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory). The standard construction of the naturals, due to John von Neumann, starts from a definition of $0$ as the empty set, $\varnothing$, and an operator $s$ on sets defined as: $$s(a)=a\cup\{a\}$$ The set of natural numbers, $\mathbb{N}$ is defined as the intersection of all sets closed under $s$ that contain the empty set. Each natural number is equal (as a set) to the set of natural numbers less than it. For example: $$3=s(2)=s(\{0,1\})=\{0,1\}\cup\{\{0,1\}\}=\{0,1,\{0,1\}\}=\{0,1,2\}$$ The set $\mathbb{N}$ together with $0$ and the successor function $s:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ satisfies the Peano axioms.

This is what he meant. $a<b$ if $s(a)\in s(b)$. As $s(0)=\varnothing$, then $s(o)\in s(1)$ so we are done.

$2''$. Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) to see more about the Peano axioms and very many interpretations (this is where $1D$ comes from and the set theroretic interpretation that guy used in his quora post)

$3$. You should use $\mathcal{Q}.\mathcal{E}.\mathcal{D}$ after the statement you prove:

> *"$7>6$, Quod Erat Demonstrandum"* not *"Quod Erat Demonstrandum: $7>6$"*

There is no exact translation,but it is used (mainly at end of proofs) with the meaning: "this completes the proof", "as required", "as desired", "as expected", "hence proved", "ergo", or other similar statements..

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't know if it is the same Quora answer, since the position changes over time. About the quantifiers (as said @halrankard2), ironically, or not, I am starting to learn about them right now. Again, thanks for the answer.

Comment: If I may, what font did you use in the "Q.E.D"? It's gorgeous. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Hey. I am glad I helped you. I used "\mathcal{}". Use it as normal LaTeX code, and write between the "{" and "}" your text. So if you write "\mathcal{Q.E.D}" you would get $\mathcal{Q.E.D}$

Comment: thank you very much.